# Call a REST API of a module controller in a play application

Tags: java, json, scala, rest, playframework

I am writing a Play 2.3.2 application.
I've the main application written in Java, and a module used by the main application written in Scala.

My module application provides some REST API that get the data from JSON and returns a JSON output.

How can I call the REST API of the module from my main application?

And how can parse the results of the computation returned by the module's Controller??

@edit

In a my module controller I have some methods like the following:

```
object BridgeController extends Controller {
def addTagToUser = CorsAction.async { request =>
     //update the tag of a user
     def updateTagToUserDB(user: User, tag: Tag): Future[Boolean] = {
       println(tag)
       val query = Json.obj("id" -> user.id,
                            "email" -> user.email) //the query object
       Users.find(query).toList.flatMap { users =>
                        val oldUser = if (users.size > 0) users(0) else user
                        val newUser = oldUser.addTags(List(tag)) //create the updated user
                        //update the document find, and create if doesn't exists
                        Users.update(query, newUser, upsert = true).flatMap{error => error match {
                                    case LastError(ok, _, _, _, _,_, _) => Future{true}
                                    case _ => Future{false} //error on update the document
                        }}                  
       }
     }


     val jsonData = request.body.asJson //get the json data
     jsonData match {
       case Some(x) => val user = x \ "user"; val tag = x \ "tag";
                    (user \ "id", user \ "email", tag \ "category", tag \ "attr") match {
                      case (userId: JsString, userEmail: JsString,
                          tagCat: JsString, tagAtr: JsString) => val myUser = new User(userId.as[String], Some(userEmail.as[String]))
                                                                 val newTag = new Tag(tagCat.as[String], tagAtr.as[String])
                                                                 updateTagToUserDB(myUser, newTag).flatMap(status => status match {
                                                                   case true => Future{Ok}//the update was executed correctly
                                                                   case false => Future{InternalServerError("Cannot access to the db now")}//update fail
                                                                 }
                                                                   )
                      case _ => Future{BadRequest("json bad formed")} // the json is bad formed

                    }

       case None => Future{BadRequest("need a json value")}

     }
   }

}
```

In a controller of my main application i can have something like this:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
     public static Result addProduct(Product product) {
             User user = product.user()
             String category = product.category()
             String nameProduct = product.nameProduct()
             //here i want to create a json like {"user": {"id" : user.id, "email",         //user.email}, tag: {"category": category, "attr", nameProduct}}
            //now i want to sent an http request to the controller module and pass the json created



    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using WebTargets - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm

Comment: @nEm No, i was hoping that play provide a mechanism for do that in a more simple way but i don't find out nothing on the web.
The alternative could be WebTargets.

Comment: Then this might be what you are looking for - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/ScalaWS

Comment: In order to answer your question, you would need to provide details on how your main application uses your scala module. Is scala module a separate controller?

Comment: Solved using WS @nbz post your answer that i accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use REST services using a PLAY framework library then you can use the WS api

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/ScalaWS

And an alternative is to use the standard Java EE

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm